# video background not showing in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

this is the html in my body
this code is for a video that covers the div with an overlay on top. I could use assistance as the video does not appear in chrome. I've tried using a webm. file and a ogv but its not working.
any and all help is appreciated.

```
 <section>
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="hero">
  <div class="container">

    <h3 class="hero-subtitle">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p class="hero-content">The main content goes here </p>
        <br>
        <h6 class="hero-excerpt">subtitle </h6>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

css page

```
#hero {
min-height: 70vh;
background:
/* top, transparent red, faked with gradient */
linear-gradient(
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85),
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)
),
/* bottom, image */
url('background_video.mp4');

background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
color: white;
.hero-subtitle {
font-size: 2rem;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 1.2;
}
.hero-content{
font-size: 1.25rem;
font-weight: 300;
}
.hero-excerpt{
font-size: 1rem;
font-weight: 300;
}
}
```

Comment: There is no reference to a video in this code... How are you calling the video?

Comment: I didnt include the video because of NDA, any video will do.

Comment: this is not valid html: `<h3 class="hero-subtitle">Lorem Ipsum</h1>` (wrong closing tag) - not sure if that's causing the issue, but should probably be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
url('background_video.mp4')
```

You can't use a video file as a background image directly. The [`url` css data type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url) when used in `background` style gets set as the `background-image` property. As such a url for that property needs to point to an image, not a video file.

**Cross browser solution**

If you want your video to be played as a background of some element you will need to put it in a container with the content you want. Overlay it by [positioning it with `position:absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and setting the appropriate [z-indexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index):

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  width:320px;
  height:180px;
}

.container video {
  position:absolute;
  width:320px;
  height:180px;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  z-index:1;
}

.container .content {
  position:relative;
  width:320px;
  height:180px;
  z-index:2;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  color:white;
  line-height:180px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video autoplay muted src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4"></video>
  <div class="content">Some content</div>
</div>
```

**Firefox only (as of June 2018)**

In firefox you can use another element as the `background-image`, so in that case you can use a `<video>` element as the background. Use the browser prefixed function [element()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image#element()). Which when passed a css id selector of the element will use that element as the background

```css
#content {
  width:320px;
  height:180px;
  background-image:-moz-element(#backgroundvideo);
  line-height:180px;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<video style="display:none;" autoplay muted id="backgroundvideo" src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4"></video>
<div id="content">Some content</div>
```