# How to use a background Video on chrome?

Tags: html, css

Hey everyone I have a slightly stupid problem, that I cannot solve apparently...
I am developing this website for an assignment, and all was looking good.
But I was using safari to design the website.

Now when I open the site on chrome, the video is not shown. I saw some of the tutorials on how to create a background video but messed up all my projects.
My problem is that I implemented the video on CSS instead of HTML. There are any easy fixes for CSS without changing all the HTML and CSS?

Here my website, I know its not perfect be patient with me :D

> https://bragainmax.netlify.app/index.html

HTML

```css
.hero{
  min-height: 80vh;
  background: url("./_images/shop.mp4") center/cover no-repeat;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.banner{
  background-color: white;
  padding: 4rem 0;
  border-radius: var(--borderRadius);
  box-shadow: var(--shadow-2);
  width: 80vw;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: var(--fixed-width);
}
```

```html
<header class="hero">
   <div class="banner">
      <h1 class="title">Bargain Max</h1>
      <h1 class="title-underline"></h1>
      <p class="home_p title">The Products that you love for the price that you need</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn"> <a href="product.html">Our Products</a> </button>
   </div>
</header>
```

Comment: does this answers your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091929/video-background-not-showing-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Υou can not import background video this way you have to do something like that.

I hope, I helped you.

```css
  .video-bg {
     object-fit: cover;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
    }

    video {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     object-fit: cover;
    }

   .hero {
     min-height: 80vh;
     background: url("./_images/shop.mp4") center/cover no-repeat;
     display: grid;
     place-items: center;
   }

  .banner{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 4rem 0;
    border-radius: var(--borderRadius);
    box-shadow: var(--shadow-2);
    width: 80vw;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: var(--fixed-width);
    position: absolute;
   }
```

```html
 <header class="hero">
    
    <div class="video-bg">

       <video preload="metadata" id="header-background-video" autoplay="" muted="" loop="" class="video"><source src="/_images/shop.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       </video>         
         
    </div>
   <div class="banner">
     <h1 class="title">Bargain Max</h1>
     <h1 class="title-underline"></h1>
     <p class="home_p title">The Products that you love for the price that you need</p>
     <button type="button" class="btn"> <a href="product.html">Our Products</a> </button>
   </div>
 </header>
```